# Is it normal to have high cholesterol after pregnancy?

Tags: obstetrics, cholesterol, breastfeeding, female, postpartum-body

Does breastfeeding moms tend to have higher cholesterol levels after pregnancy?

Comment: Depends on how long after pregnancy and how high cholesterol. Elevated cholesterol is necessary during pregnancy, the fetus needs it to develop properly. Note: always check the LDL/HDL ratio too, not just the cholesterol. It should be under 3.5, but under 2 is it really good. HDL helps to clean up cholesterol from blood vessels.

Comment: @inf3rno Sounds like the makings of a good answer, but comments aren't answers and tend to be ephemeral. Please consider turning your comment into an answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory I am just a bioengineer, not a practitioner. Maybe somebody with more experience has a better answer.

Comment: @inf3rno There is no requirement for being a medical professional here. In fact, being a medical professional counts for nothing since we have no way of verifying who is or isn't. All that's required is sound answers with supporting sources.

Comment: Thanls inf3rno - how about 6 months after pregnancy? Is there a time frame when it should return to normal range after pregnancy? TIA